# Get a URL that will load ajax content of a packed solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a packaged web application with multiple ajax calls that will load html content in the middle of the website.

Is there a way to go directly to one of the ajax calls from the URL instead of manually clicking the buttons to reach the required content on the page immediately?

As a sample, i want to show the content of this page like i clicked the button without clicking it using JavaScript, jQuery, or manual click.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: You mean, you want to redirect automatically to a different URL, when accessing the page? Does [`window.location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) not work?

Comment: So you can simply remove the `onclick` event. Then whenever you go to that page, it automatically happens.

Comment: you mean you don't want a button click as a trigger, instead you want a change in the URL to make the changes in the DOM? Please be informed that any changes in the DOM after the DOM has been delivered by the server is possible by javascript.

Comment: @Geshode, no because Ajax is updating the page or part of it without leaving it. I want to go to the updated page directly while the current logic require me to click a button to execute the ajax

Comment: @kapitan,this is exactly what i want but i was wondering if i can reach to the updated dom directly and bypass the initial state of the app.

Comment: Can you make a demo of your current situation? It's kind of hard to understand. Also the requirements are a bit confusing; `i was wondering if i can reach to the updated dom directly and bypass the initial state of the app` - why not then just change the initial state of the app?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen, i can't change the initial state because it's a packaged solution. I will  try to implement some example

Comment: @Ali123 Not sure what a packaged solution means, but I'm pretty sure the only possible thing to do is to show a default state and then click the button either with JS or manually by the user. If that isn't fast enough, then you need to find out exactly what is making it slow and make those things faster. This is also why some apps still used a loading animation or spinner. Would a spinner work for you? A demo/example would sitll be best :)